# The value for annotation attribute FindBy.using must be a constant expression

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

We are facing some issue in the @FindBy in the page object model. My Scenario is i need to get a values from the excel and example given below

```
protected static final String Loginfield= "test" -  Webelement ID
@FindBy(how=How.ID, using=Loginfield)
public WebElement test;
```

Anyone can you give some solutions?

Comment: What error you are getting? Is protected static final String Loginfield is fetched from excel? If yes value in this variable should be loaded before you initialize page(pageFactory.init)

Comment: @deepk I am getting error "The value for annotation attribute FindBy.using must be a constant expression". Yes i am fetching the data in the excel qand already i have defined in the pagefactory in the constructor

Comment: It looks like you can not user variable in FindBy. Values of locator in @FindBy ( or any annotation) should be **compile** time constant. Refer [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/annotations.html)

Comment: It worked for me if I had `final` before the variable type.
So my var definition looked like:
`final String var1 = "elementXpath"`